# How do Dynamic Attributes work?

Tags: dynamic, attributes

Reading in the [doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#2125133640), it is mentioned in the example of `Dynamic` that this way of writing the code does not work:

```
data = {.1, .5, .3, .9, .2};
Table[Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]], {i, 5}]
```

The reason is because `Dynamic` is `HoldFirst`.

Now is that really the reason? look at this:

```
Clear[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_] := g[x]
Table[f[i], {i, 5}]
(*{g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5]}*)
```

It is clear that the substitution of `i` happed to the function `f` inside Table.

So what is the reason that substitution of `i` happed in the `f` case and does not happened in the `Dynamic` case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is more like `Dynamic`:

```
Clear[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
(*f[x_]:=g[x]*)
Table[f[i], {i, 5}]
(*  {f[i], f[i], f[i], f[i], f[i]}  *)
```

By giving `f` a definition, it evaluated while in `Table`, during which the `i` got evaluated.

Comment: Is it like that? so `Dynamic` is not really a function!

Comment: @Algohi `Dynamic` hasn't any hidden properties. The difference is that in the first table and Michael's example the `i` stays as a held argument. `Dynamic` stays to inform FE to take care of it. In your second example `HoldFirst` is acting only for a moment and it's passed to `g` which doesn't have `Hold*` attributes.

Comment: @Kuba, ok I got it. Thanks

Comment: @Michael E2 one last thing to make it clear, if the case is as you said and as @kuba said, then why f and Dynamic behaves differently in example like this `{Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x + 1], f[x + 1]}`

Comment: @Kuba yes and why Dynamic evaluates its argument (x+1) whereas f does not. even if I re-evaluate the cell (where x will have a value) same case happens

Comment: @Algohi Both are sending held x+1 to Kernel, but in first case DynamicBox[x+1] is back while in second f[x+1] boxes. And boxes are static unless FrontEnd decides they are not, and it decides "better keep track of that DynamicBox content". Maybe I shouldn't say Dynamic has no hidden properties due to the way FrontEnd treats them. Dynamic related tutorials may be of help. I'm reading them from time to time and there is always something I missed previously.

Comment: @Algohi about reevaluation, `f` still has HoldFirst Attribute and no DownValues defined so it stays with unevaluated content. And Dynamic is still supported by FE.

Comment: @Kuba, Smiling while reading your replies :) You are great man. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have different vision about what the problem is.

It looks like the reason is not because the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Dynamic` but rather because of `Dynamic` and `Slider` themselves.
`Slider` and `Dynamic` does not respond to `Hold` function and to `HoldAll` `Attributes` of `Table`

In all of these example, `Hold` does not work:

```
HoldComplete[Slider[]]
HoldComplete[Slider[Dynamic[x]]]
HoldComplete[Slider[Dynamic[x]]]
HoldComplete[Dynamic[x + 1]]
```

[image]

In the above mentioned case of `Table`, `Table` has attribute `HoldAll`. But this does not work with `Slider` and `Dynamic`.

```
a = {.1, .5, .3, .9, .2};
Table[Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]], {i, 2}] // Trace
Table[Dynamic[data[[i]]], {i, 2}] // Trace
```

[image]

As you can see that `Table` does not hold its argument.

It looks like the `Dynamic` `HoldFirst` is not the reason for this issue but it is the `Slider` and `Dynamic` themselves evaluate inside `Hold`.